# Troubles with Excel date functions (time of service in a company)

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula

I am working in Excel and I'm having problems with getting right results by using functions.

1st one is trying to subtract working time for pension minus working time in the company in the format of YYMMDD (090512), for instance if I do 090512-030327 it will give me 60185 instead of 060115

2nd one is using DATEDIF to get the years of service until todays date in the same format as in the 1st. I'm using the formula

```
=DATEDIF(B9;C9;"md")&DATEDIF(B9;C9;"ym")&DATEDIF(B9;C9;"y")
```

but the problem i have is the missing 0's when the day/month/year is a single digit, so instead of 121109 I get 12119

Haven't tried much since I don't know much about functions in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is generated because you are subtracting thrity thousand three houndred and twenty-seven to ninety thousand five hundred and twelve. You are basically not storing those numbers as dates but as actual numbers, therefore Excel won't treat them as dates but as numbers. If you want to keep them as number and still subtract them, you shall turn into dates at least in your formulas. Assuming they are all correctly reported as YYMMDD with all 6 digits specified (let's say in column A starting from the second row), you can use something like:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A2,2),MID(A2,3,2),RIGHT(A2,2))
```

This will return you the value as an actual date. You can then use it as needed.

The second problem (assuming your original formula is actually working even if your dates are stored as numbers) can be solved using the [TEXT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c) function. Something like this might work:

```
=TEXT(DATEDIF(B9,C9,"md"),"00")&TEXT(DATEDIF(B9,C9,"ym"),"00")&TEXT(DATEDIF(B9,C9,"y"),"00")
```

Note that this will still return not a date but a text (which will be turned into a number if you apply a mathematical operator to it).

---

**EDIT**

Following the comments, here is a way to calculate the difference in those fake-date values:

| Value 1 | Value 2 |  | Years 1 | Months 1 | Days 1 | Value 1 [days] |  | Years 2 | Months 2 | Days 2 | Value 2 [days] |  | Value 3 (Value 1 minus Value 2) [days] | Years 3 | Months 3 | Days 3 | Value 3 |  | Value 3 (one formula) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 390426 | 250014 |  | =LEFT(A2,2) | =MID(A2,3,2) | =RIGHT(A2,2) | =F2+E2*30+D2*360 |  | =LEFT(B2,2) | =MID(B2,3,2) | =RIGHT(B2,2) | =K2+J2*30+I2*360 |  | =G2-L2 | =QUOTIENT(N2,360) | =QUOTIENT(MOD(N2,360),30) | =MOD(MOD(N2,360),30) | =TEXT(O2,"00")&TEXT(P2,"00")&TEXT(Q2,0) |  | =TEXT(QUOTIENT(((RIGHT(A2,2)+MID(A2,3,2)*30+LEFT(A2,2)*360)-(RIGHT(B2,2)+MID(B2,3,2)*30+LEFT(B2,2)*360)),360),"00")&TEXT(QUOTIENT(MOD(((RIGHT(A2,2)+MID(A2,3,2)*30+LEFT(A2,2)*360)-(RIGHT(B2,2)+MID(B2,3,2)*30+LEFT(B2,2)*360)),360),30),"00")&TEXT(MOD(MOD(((RIGHT(A2,2)+MID(A2,3,2)*30+LEFT(A2,2)*360)-(RIGHT(B2,2)+MID(B2,3,2)*30+LEFT(B2,2)*360)),360),30),0) |
| 230614 | 170116 |  | =LEFT(A3,2) | =MID(A3,3,2) | =RIGHT(A3,2) | =F3+E3*30+D3*360 |  | =LEFT(B3,2) | =MID(B3,3,2) | =RIGHT(B3,2) | =K3+J3*30+I3*360 |  | =G3-L3 | =QUOTIENT(N3,360) | =QUOTIENT(MOD(N3,360),30) | =MOD(MOD(N3,360),30) | =TEXT(O3,"00")&TEXT(P3,"00")&TEXT(Q3,0) |  | =TEXT(QUOTIENT(((RIGHT(A3,2)+MID(A3,3,2)*30+LEFT(A3,2)*360)-(RIGHT(B3,2)+MID(B3,3,2)*30+LEFT(B3,2)*360)),360),"00")&TEXT(QUOTIENT(MOD(((RIGHT(A3,2)+MID(A3,3,2)*30+LEFT(A3,2)*360)-(RIGHT(B3,2)+MID(B3,3,2)*30+LEFT(B3,2)*360)),360),30),"00")&TEXT(MOD(MOD(((RIGHT(A3,2)+MID(A3,3,2)*30+LEFT(A3,2)*360)-(RIGHT(B3,2)+MID(B3,3,2)*30+LEFT(B3,2)*360)),360),30),0) |
| 541124 | 371227 |  | =LEFT(A4,2) | =MID(A4,3,2) | =RIGHT(A4,2) | =F4+E4*30+D4*360 |  | =LEFT(B4,2) | =MID(B4,3,2) | =RIGHT(B4,2) | =K4+J4*30+I4*360 |  | =G4-L4 | =QUOTIENT(N4,360) | =QUOTIENT(MOD(N4,360),30) | =MOD(MOD(N4,360),30) | =TEXT(O4,"00")&TEXT(P4,"00")&TEXT(Q4,0) |  | =TEXT(QUOTIENT(((RIGHT(A4,2)+MID(A4,3,2)*30+LEFT(A4,2)*360)-(RIGHT(B4,2)+MID(B4,3,2)*30+LEFT(B4,2)*360)),360),"00")&TEXT(QUOTIENT(MOD(((RIGHT(A4,2)+MID(A4,3,2)*30+LEFT(A4,2)*360)-(RIGHT(B4,2)+MID(B4,3,2)*30+LEFT(B4,2)*360)),360),30),"00")&TEXT(MOD(MOD(((RIGHT(A4,2)+MID(A4,3,2)*30+LEFT(A4,2)*360)-(RIGHT(B4,2)+MID(B4,3,2)*30+LEFT(B4,2)*360)),360),30),0) |

Copy it in a new sheet. In A:B you have the source date. In D:R the calculations and solution (column R) spread on a range. In column T you have the solution with a single cell formula (basically the same thing you have in D:R but obtained via 1 long formula).

Days, months and years are traded with a month made of 30 days and a year made of 12 months (therefore 360 days) as requested.

Comment: The 2nd solution worked splendidly, but I'm having troubles with the 1st one, because I don't know how to use it to subtract and put into a 6 digit format.

Sorry for the incompetence and many thanks

Comment: You can use again the TEXT function to turn it into a 6 digit format. Something like `=TEXT(A2,"YYMMDD")` should work. About the subtraction: what you are looking for exactly? Do you want to count days? Because of leap years not every year is the same and of course not every month have the same number of days.

Comment: I'm trying to get 390426 - 250014 = 140412 and with the formula =TEXT(DATE(LEFT(B2;2);MID(B2;3;2);RIGHT(B2;2))-DATE(LEFT(C2;2);MID(C2;3;2);RIGHT(C2;2));"YYMMDD") it gives me 140512, the year and day seem to be correct but the month suddenly receives +1

Comment: So you basically need to: chop the data; subtract day 2 from day 1 and if negative turn into positive and "steal" 1 month from month 1; subtract month 2 from month 1 and if negative turn into positive and "steal" 1 year from year 1; subtract year 2 from year 1. Is this the logic you apply? Doesn't make much sense to me, but still...

Comment: Wait, those numbers: are they just the "actual amount"? They are not date composed by years, months and days in the classical sense, but the actual "sum" of years, months and days? If so, how many days do you count for a month and how many months do you count for a year? Like 365,25 days per year and therefore 30,4375 days per month?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining well, I'm still new to this, it is a number and not a date, they took the days, months and years and put it into a single number. I probably confused the situation by mentioning the YYMMDD. 

I tried this formula =TEXT(LEFT(B2;2)-LEFT(C2;2);"00")&TEXT(MID(B2;3;2)-MID(C2;3;2);"00")&TEXT(RIGHT(B2;2)-RIGHT(C2;2);"00"), which gives me the right result for the first one but for the rest it just adds random dashes.

390426 - 250014 = 140412
230614 - 170116 = 0605-02
541124 - 371227 = 17-01-03

Comment: Those radom dashes are not random, they are just negative values. For example: `230614 - 170116 = 0605-02` because `14 - 16 = -2`. If you want to subtract like that, you need to establish how many days is a month and how many months is a year. Since a year is roughly 365,25 days and a year has 12 months, i'd go for a month of 30,4375 days and a year of 365,25 days. Would that be ok?

Comment: Anything is fine as long as it works, I've managed to get rid of the minuses with IF and the formula =TEXT(IF(LEFT(B4;2)-LEFT(C4;2)<0;(LEFT(B4;2)-LEFT(C4;2))*-1;LEFT(B4;2)-LEFT(C4;2));"00")&TEXT(IF(MID(B4;3;2)-MID(C4;3;2)<0;(MID(B4;3;2)-MID(C4;3;2))*-1;MID(B4;3;2)-MID(C4;3;2));"00")&TEXT(IF(RIGHT(B4;2)-RIGHT(C4;2)<0;(RIGHT(B4;2)-RIGHT(C4;2))*-1;RIGHT(B4;2)-RIGHT(C4;2));"00")

But the only problem now is when let's say 14-16 occurs it gives 02, which should reset to 30 and get minus'd by the leftover 2. I'm guessing this is where the seperate cells with the values of years/months come in.

Comment: Or I can try to add another IF to increase it by 30 after the *-1

Comment: So the standard month has 30 days and the standard year has 360 days?

Comment: Yeah my mentor said those would work

Comment: Answer edited to provide the additional solution. Send feedback.